# Enabling Persistence of WCF Workflow Service

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

how to Enable Persistence of WCF Workflow Service from the MVC Web application ?

Answer (score 0):

You add a `<sqlWorkflowInstanceStore>` element to the web.config. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773.aspx) for details.

Comment: My scenario : i have MVC application and i have added reference of the WCF workflow service in it. now i am able to initiate that workflow service from my MVC application but i want to persist data also how do i achieve it ? what to pass into the new Uri(hostBaseAddress) in WorkflowServiceHost?

Comment: You don't. Instead you use the `<workflowIdle>` behavior and let the WorkflowServiceHost sort things out. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee818710.aspx As an alternative you can also embed Persist activities in you workflow for extra persist points.

Comment: any example or tutorial on that ?

Comment: @Maurice Could you please elaborate on your comment above. Is there a way that I can set this behavior from code? This is something I'm searching for and the use case of OP is my exact use case.